# Location permission dialog is shown and immediately disappears

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

The iOS dialog prompts and disappears after half a second:

```
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("In Use \(locationManager.location?.description)")
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("always \(locationManager.location)")
        }
```

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using SWReavealViewController.
Xcode9, compiled for iOS 8.0, both simulator and real device

Comment: Where is this code executed?

Comment: I tried in different places

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `locationManager` variable won't live beyond the scope of its definition (the function where that snippet of code lives), so it is deallocated before the user can respond to the dialog.

If you move `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` up to a class variable, it should stick around.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` to the very beginning of the your `ViewController` class. (Outside of `viewDidLoad()` function). Hope it helps you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```